# Loop over sets of variables PHP to CSV

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to design a User Interface that would allow people to make multiple requests (for all of the items displayed in their search results) simultaneously. I've got it set to where an individual request will work perfectly, but it will only pick up the last item on a group request. Is there a way to loop around and pick up all of the variables and write out to a new line each time? I'm sure that using the same 'name=""' value is wrong, but I'm not wise enough to know what's right.

HTML:

```
  <form name="single" action="get.php" method="post">
    <table>
      <tbody>
        <tr >
          <td colspan="2"><p>Convert All Items in Cart <br>
              <span style="font-weight:bold;font-size:10px;color:red">CAUTION: Only use the "Convert All Items" field if all titlegroups are going to be converted from and to the exact same asset types<span> </p></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="titleGalleryViewLabel" style="font-weight:bold" colspan="2"><br />
            <p>Additional Requirements:</p>
            <br/>
            <textarea name="textarea1" rows="6" cols="20" style="width:230px"></textarea>
            <hr/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="titleGalleryViewLabel" style="font-weight:bold" colspan="2"><p>Rush Date: </p>
            <br/>
            <input name="date1" type="text" class="datepicker" placeholder="Rush request dates are not guaranteed." style="height:2em;width:230px" />
            <hr/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="titleGalleryViewLabel" style="font-weight:bold" colspan="2"><p>Select Source Type</p>
            <br/>
            <select name="source1" style="width:230px;resize:both" multiple required>
              <option disabled selected hidden>Select Source Type</option>
              <optgroup label="Select All that Apply">
              <option>Lets just say I'm saving a lot of space</option>
              </optgroup>
            </select>
            <hr/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="titleGalleryViewLabel" style="font-weight:bold" colspan="2"><p>Request Type</p>
            <br/>
            <select name="type1" style="width:230px;resize:both" multiple required>
              <option disabled selected hidden>Select Request Type</option>
              <optgroup label="Select All that Apply">
              <<option>Lets just say I'm saving a lot of space</option>
              </optgroup>
            </select>
            <hr/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="titleGalleryViewLabel">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="csbutt"></input></td>
          <td><input class="csbutt" type="reset" name="reset" value="Reset Form"></input></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
<input name="cwi" type="hidden" value=" "/>
<input name="publisher" type="hidden" value="Pub 1"/>
<input name="title" type="hidden" value="Title 1"/>
<input name="parent" type="hidden" value="ISBN 1"/>
<input name="author" type="hidden" value="Author 1"/>
<input name="bill" type="hidden" value=" "/>

<input name="cwi" type="hidden" value=" "/>
<input name="publisher" type="hidden" value="Pub 2"/>
<input name="title" type="hidden" value="Title 2"/>
<input name="parent" type="hidden" value="ISBN 2"/>
<input name="author" type="hidden" value="Author 2"/>
<input name="bill" type="hidden" value=" "/>
  </form>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
require 'class.phpmailer.php';


date_default_timezone_set('America/Kentucky/Louisville');
$date = time();
$day= getdate();

if(isset($_POST['source1'])){
    $org = 'request.csv';
    $new = $date.'_requested.csv';
    if (!copy($org, $new)) {
        echo "Failed to copy";
    }
    $del = ",";
    $data[1] = $_POST['cwi'];
    $data[2] = $_POST['date1'];
    $data[3] = $_POST['date1'];
    $data[4] = $_POST['parent'];
    $data[5] = $_POST['parent'];
    $data[6] = $_POST['publisher'];
    $data[7] = $_POST['title'];
    $data[8] = $_POST['author'];
    $data[9] = $_POST['bill'];
    $data[10] = $_POST['source1'];
    $data[11] = $_POST['type1'];
    $data[12] = $_POST['textarea1'];
    $file = fopen($date.'_requested.csv', "a");
    $data = "\r\n".implode($del, $data);
    fwrite($file, $data);
    fclose($file);
    $pub = $_POST['publisher'];

    $to = 'foo@bar.com';
    $toname = 'John Doe';
    $from = "foo2@bar2.com";
    $fromname = 'Jane Doe';
    $subject = "Foo bar foo bar";
    $message = "<html>
        <head>
        <title>Request</title>
        </head>
        <body>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Body</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        </body>
        </html>";

//PHP Mailer
    $mail = new PHPMailer();
    $mail->IsSendmail();
    $mail->FromName = $fromname;
    $mail->From = $from;
    $mail->AddAddress($to, $toname);
    $mail->Subject = $subject;
    $mail->Body = $message;
    $mail->AddAttachment($date.'_requested.csv');
    $mail->isHTML(true);
    $result = $mail->send();
}
else{
    echo "Something went wrong";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have a form submit an array of variables for your PHP to parse, by appending [] to the variable name. So this:

```
<textarea name="textarea1" rows="6" cols="20" style="width:230px"></textarea>
```

becomes:

```
<textarea name="textarea1[]" rows="6" cols="20" style="width:230px"></textarea>
```

Source: http://php.net/manual/en/faq.html.php

Comment: It's erroring out on the delimiter line of the PHP. Do I need to change the `$del = ",";` to something else?

Comment: You will need to change the back end as well. All of the $_POST variables will now be arrays that you must cycle through simultaneously. So get the total number of rows from, for example, count($_POST['id']), then do a `for ($i = 0; $i < count($_POST['id']); $i++) {`. In that loop, you would write each row to the csv file, getting $_POST['id'][$i], $_POST['textarea1'][$i], etc.

Comment: As Walter says, "Donny, you're out of your element." I'm going to go take some PHP classes and then come back to your answer and try again. Web design I've done for a while, but this more complex programming is new territory.

Answer (score 0):

You could do somthing like
this:

```
<input name="post_data[]" type="text">
<input name="post_data[]" type="number">
<input name="post_data[]" type="email">
```

server side:

```
$array_of_posted_data_from_form=$_POST["post_data"];
scv='';
foreach($array_of_posted_data_from_form as $value_from_data_from_form_array){
   $scv .="\r\n".$value_from_data_from_form_array;
}
```